# What are the advantages of using MySQL VIEWS in PHP application?

Tags: php, mysql, database, view

I am little new to PHP, MySQL and web development. I have seen MySQL Views are "Virtual Tables" and can be used to represent data table virtually. And my problems are,

1. Are there any performance increment when we use MySQL Views in a PHP 7 MySQL application?
2. Are there any security increment?
3. Can we use MySQL Views for JSON REST API requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As far as I know. The view is like you save a query to a database. So you can save time to write a complex query.
2. I think yes. Because you can grant users access to view rather than directly to the table.
3. To get the data is yes, but a function like edit and delete I don't think so.

Comment: Almost completely correct - VIEWs will not yield a performance benefit. At best, they will be no faster. At best they will be slower and executed as a sub-select.